# I can't pull my app with the command shoutem pull-app How can i fix it?

Tags: shoutem

For some reason I getting this message "Due to a bug in the `npm`, app's path can't contain spaces" . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdI0i.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since there's a bug in `npm`, you need to download your code from some different directory. On the picture I can see that you're located in `C:\Users\Christian K` directory which contains a space. Try relocating to `C:\Users` with:

```
cd ..
```

That path doesn't contain spaces and you can do:

```
shoutem pull-app
```

Comment: Glad to help! :) If that's the solution, please accept the answer.